# Passing a list of strings in a QGIS attribute table with column type: String List

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have a GeoJSON file in QGIS and I created a column in its attribute table with column type: String list.
I want to each cell to have two strings. The two strings are urls.

I tried:

1. `'https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg', 'http://freakplaces.com/img/Cannon_Beach17.jpg'`

2. `['https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg', 'http://freakplaces.com/img/Cannon_Beach17.jpg']`
3. `list('https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg', 'http://freakplaces.com/img/Cannon_Beach17.jpg')`

These didn't work. Is there something I'm missing?

Relevant image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmQA5.jpg

Comment: You want to write these strings into the attribute table?

Comment: Yes. Since it's a geojson file, I want each row in the column Images to contain a list of strings. The first element in the list should be a url and the second element another url.

Comment: Are these URL the same for all features?

Comment: Yes, every feature should have these two URLs.

Answer (score 3):

Open the field calculator.

[image]

Choose the field you want to add or edit, then enter the following expression:

`'https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg, http://freakplaces.com/img/Cannon_Beach17.jpg'`

What you did was selecting all features which had this text in that field.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your field must be of type **QStringList**.
You can check this in the properties of your layer in the **Fields** tab.

Then you update your field with the following method (array('value1','value2', ...)):

`array('https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg', 'http://freakplaces.com/img/Cannon_Beach17.jpg')`

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to create a field with the type QStringList. The string related options are Text (string) and String List which result in field types Qstring and QVariantList respectively.

Comment: You can choose this type by using the add field button (more types are available) in the attribute table and not in the field calculator

Comment: The only options I get are whole number (integer), whole number (integer 64), decimal number (real), text (string), string list, and boolean. image: https://imgur.com/pW6DSdN

Comment: Curious, I tried on QGIS 3.4 and QGIS 3.14 and I have many more choices. You can also add a field via the fields tab in the properties but I think it won't change anything.

Comment: That's weird. I also have QGIS 3.14 and I tried to add a new field from the fields tab in properties and the choices are the same. Maybe it has to do with the type of file that is being edited. My observations are for a GeoJSON file.

Comment: I have just tried it and you are right. What a pity!